# don't show on panel

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I am trying to write a simple aplication (a continuously changing label on a window on the upper left side of the screen) and I don't want it to be seen on panel but only on system tray.Because it will run for a long time. How can I do that? Thanks.

PS: I am using python and pyqt on Linux. I tried SplashScreen but when I clicked on the window it disapears. I have a contexmenu on the window, so I must click on it.!

http://www.qtcentre.org/attachment.php?attachmentid=4686&d=1274802065

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. I set the window flag as "Qt.Popup". Now there in no window on the panel.